Map of L groups induces map of Hecke algebras
I would like to ask why will a map of $L$ groups induce a map of Hecke algebras in the opposite direction.
More precisely, let $G_1, G_2$ be unramified reductive groups over a non-Archimedean local field $F$ with hyperspecial subgroups $K_1, K_2$ respectively. If $$r: {}^LG_1 \to {}^LG_2$$ is an $L$-map, prove that there is a unique algebra homomorphism $$\hat r: C^\infty_c(G_2(F)//K_2) \to C^\infty_c(G_1(F)//K_1)$$ such that the traces match, i.e. if $\pi$ is an irreducible admissible $K_1$-unramified representation of $G_1(F)$ with $K_2$-unramified transfer $r(\pi)$ to $G_2(F)$, then $tr\; r(\pi)(f) = tr\; \pi(\hat r(f))$.
This is extracted from exercise 19.2 of Getz-Hahn's book 'an introduction to automorphic representations: with a view toward trace formulae'. I guess I might need to use the Satake isomorphism, but I couldn't really get anywhere. I will be happy if anyone can spare some time to tell me the construction of $\hat r$ (and even better, why it satisfies the conditions on traces). Thanks!
Remark: A morphism of $L$-groups ${}^LG_1 \to {}^LG_2$ is a continuous homomorphism commuting with the projections to $Gal_F$ such that its restriction to the neutral components is induced by a map of algebraic groups $\hat G_1 \to \hat G_2$.
